# Pro Asp.net core MVC how create list of view and pass the data list to the controllers (How can i pass list of data from view to controllers)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

```
'public class CutData
        {
            [Key]
            public int DataID { get; set; }//before

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Tool")]
            public string Tool { get; set; }//before
         // (skip 66 )....
            public string Location { get; set; }//before

        }'
```

model CutData

```
'
    @model List<CutData>
        <a class="btn btn-primary classAdd" style="margin:5px;">Add row</a>
        <div class="editDiv" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow-x :auto;">
            <form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <table id="editTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th class="sticky">Cut Ref</th>
                                <th>Tool</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
        @*(skip...)*@
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                           {
                            <tr class="newcutDataInput">
                                <td><div class="form-group"><input type="hidden" name="Model[i].DataID" /></div></td>
                               .....
                                <td><button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>
                            </tr>
                           }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button style="position:fixed; margin-top: 40px;" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveAll" asp-controller="Home" type="submit">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on("click", ".classAdd", function () {
                    var i = 1;
                    var contacttr = '<tr class="newcutDataInput">' +
                                '<td><div class="form-group"><input type="hidden" name="Model[i].DataID"/></div></td>' +
                               @*(skip...)*@          
                        '<td><button type = "button" id = "btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs"> Remove</button></td > ' +
                        '</tr>';
                    $('#editTable').append(contacttr); // Adding these controls to Main table class
                    rowCount++;
                });
            }); // Adding these controls to Main table class

'
```

view call Edit

```
'

    [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Edit(List<CutData> cutDatas)
            {
                try
                {

                    //context.CutDatas.Add(cutDatas);

                    //List<CutData> cutList = new List<CutData>();
                    //foreach (var c in cutDatas)
                    //{

                    //    cutList.Add(new CutData()
                    //    {
                    //        DataID = c.DataID,
                   //             .........
                    //        Location = c.Location,

                    //    });
                    //}
                    //context.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("CutList");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }

'
```

controllor

Pro Asp.net core MVC how create list of view and pass the data list to the controllers (How can i pass list of data from view to controllers)- I know how can i pass data from view to controllers but I don't know how can I pass List of Data(add rows) to the controllers. Pls fix the view and controller 
I am using Migrations.

Comment: I don't know this method I should using for the  list of data. should I using List? IList? array? collection? bulk? pls teach and fix for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `List<CutData>` to receive the modified data.

The `name attribute` in the view needs to match the `cutDatas parameter` that Edit action receives.

In addition, **the submit button does not need to add asp-controller**. This will cause you to click on the button and enter the default method of Home instead of Edit action.

And the `index` for adding rows in js needs to be added **on the basis of model data count**.

```
 @model List<CutData>    
<a class="btn btn-primary classAdd" style="margin:5px;">Add row</a>
    <div class="editDiv" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow-x :auto;">
        <form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <table id="editTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Tool</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <tr class="newcutDataInput">
                                <td><div class="form-group"><input type="hidden" name="cutDatas[@i].DataID" asp-for="@Model[i].DataID" /></div></td>
                                <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="cutDatas[@i].Tool" asp-for="@Model[i].Tool" /></div></td>
                                <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="cutDatas[@i].Location" asp-for="@Model[i].Location" /></div></td>
                                <td><button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button style="position:fixed; margin-top: 40px;" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveAll" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                  var rowCount = @Model.Count;
                    $(document).on("click", ".classAdd", function () {
                        var contacttr = '<tr class="newcutDataInput">' +
                            '<td><div class="form-group"><input type="hidden" name="cutDatas[' + rowCount + '].DataID"/></div></td>' +
                            '<td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="cutDatas[' + rowCount + '].Tool" /></div></td>' +
                            '<td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="cutDatas[' + rowCount + '].Location"/></div></td>' +
                            '<td><button type = "button" id = "btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs"> Remove</button></td > ' +
                            '</tr>';
                        $('#editTable').append(contacttr); // Adding these controls to Main table class
                        rowCount++;
                    });
             }); // Adding these controls to Main table class
        </script>
```

Here is the debug result :

[image]